# Taking user input and confirming format

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, input

I am new to Ruby: I have only completed the codecademy for it and I have very limited experience with Rails.

I am trying to create a simple function that will take a user's input and see if it meets the right criteria for a serial number:  three capital letters, a dash, and then seven numbers.

Here is what I have so far:

```
"enter serial"
serialNumber = gets.chomp

serNumarr = serialNumber.split("")

caps = serNumarr[0..2]
dash = serNumarr[3]
nums = serNumarr[4..10]

if dash != "-"
    puts "not a serial Number"
end
```

Now I have also asked on other forums and I was told to utilize this code:

```
def letter?(lookAhead)
  lookAhead =~ /[[:alpha:]]/
end
```

But I have zero experience with regular expressions.  How can I use the above code to solve my problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a contrived solution:

```
puts "enter three capital letters, a dash, and then seven numbers:"
input = gets.chomp  #=> note that input is a String

if input =~ /^[A-Z]{3}-\d{7}$/
  puts "valid"
else
  puts "invalid"
end
```

Breaking down the regular expression into human-readable language:

- `^` means start of line (unless it is in a character class where it's negation)
- `[A-Z]{3}` means 3 of any uppercase letter; `[]` represents a character class (i.e. uppercase letters) and the associated`{3}` means exactly three of the character class
- `-` is the dash character
- `\d{7}` means exactly 7 digits
- `$` means end of line

If you don't have experience with regular expressions, it'll be worth your while to find a tutorial and invest the time to learn the basics.  And http://rubular.com/ is an online regular expression editor that I can't endorse stronly enough.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I would have never been able to come up with a regex even half as easy as that.  Your step-by-step explanation has really helped as well.